# Changing json file creation destination from dropbox to google drive

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

i need to have this code have the create the json file inside of google drive instead of drop box

I have experimented with a few things but i am not quite knowledgeable enough to make this change, i would show less code but i do not know where the problem lies

```
function main(spreadsheet_id) {
  var json_dict = fillDict(spreadsheet_id)
  var json_obj = convertDictToJSON(json_dict)
  sendJSONToDropbox(json_obj)
};

function sendJSONToDropbox(json_object) {
  var timestamp = timeStamp()
  var parameters = {
    "path": "/json_jobs/rhino" + "-" + timestamp + ".json",
    "mode": "add", // do not overwrite
    "autorename": true,
    "mute": false // notify Dropbox client
  };


  var headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'dropbox_access_token',
    "Dropbox-API-Arg": JSON.stringify(parameters)
  };


  var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": headers,
    "payload": json_object
  };

  var API_url = "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload";
  var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(API_url, options).getContentText());
```

Comment: Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52777524/how-to-save-a-json-file-in-google-apps-script). You want to remove all code from `function sendJSONToDropbox` downwards as this only handles export to DropBox. Replace `sendJSONToDropbox(json_obj)` with code to save in Google Drive instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) class, it is not too difficult:

```js
function sendJSONToGDrive(json_object) {
  var timestamp = timeStamp();
  var fileName = "rhino" + "-" + timestamp + ".json";
  var fileContent = JSON.stringify(json_object);

  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('YOUR_FOLDER_ID');
  myFolder.createFile(fileName, fileContent, 'application/json');
}
```

You just have to replace `YOUR_FOLDER_ID` for your actual destination folder's id.

For more information on how to use the Drive API from Google Apps Script, I recommend you check out the following link: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive